# make Apache reload skipping vhost on error

Tags: configuration, virtualhost, apache-2.4

have several vhost configured with there own conf file under conf.d. This works fine, but ever so often i have to make changes to one of the files and the reload apache. Is there a way where apache would skip that file if there is an error so that the other sites still goes up on a reload?

This is a prod site (and yes i should test all first, but that is not always practical). It would be nice if I could change the file for domain1.conf do a service httpd restart and then if there is an error in the file that today would cause apache not to start at all it would simply skip that conf file and load start with all the others.

Hope this would work

Regards

Tore

Comment: sure, test every file independently and skip the one giving you errors. Share the script when you're done ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply ensure that your config is correct **before** you issue a restart/reload

```
apachectl configtest
```

> [**`configtest`**](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/apachectl.html) : 
>   Run a configuration file syntax test. It parses the configuration files and either reports Syntax Ok or detailed information about the particular syntax error. This is equivalent to `apachectl -t`.

Comment: But if the syntax is ok but a path to for example a cert file or a file root file location is wrong will that show?

Comment: create a vhost with some bad paths and test it - I don't think you will fail a syntax test over a bad path.

Comment: Just added a "_" to a cert path and it returned a "does not exist" error, so thats a solved for me! Thanks!